# Why is this simple regular expression not working

Tags: scala

This is a sample code from a scala book. 
This object has a method that will remove any html tags in a given string.
But for reason, it removes the entire string content not just HTML tags. May i know why?

```
object HtmlUtils {
 def removeMarkup(input: String) = {
    input.replaceAll("""</?\w[^>]*>""","")
    input.replaceAll("<.*>","")
   }
 }


val ahtmlText = "<html><body><h1>Introduction</h1></body></html>"

val anewhtmlText = HtmlUtils.removeMarkup(ahtmlText)

println(anewhtmlText)

println(s"Before removing html tags, the string was $ahtmlText and after rmoving html tags the string became $anewhtmlText")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 2nd `replaceAll` is not needed and will remove everything due to greedy match by `.*`.  Also, your 1st `replaceAll` can be generalized, if wanted.  The following revised `removeMarkup` should work for you:

```
object HtmlUtils {
  def removeMarkup(input: String) = {
    input.replaceAll("""</?[^>]*>""", "")
  }
}

scala> val ahtmlText = "<html><body><h1>Introduction</h1></body></html>"
ahtmlText: String = <html><body><h1>Introduction</h1></body></html>

scala> val anewhtmlText = HtmlUtils.removeMarkup(ahtmlText)
anewhtmlText: String = Introduction
```